# Is that overfitting problem? or what is going on?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

This the data:

```
square  AP-00  AP-01  AP-02   AP-03  AP-04  AP-05  AP-06   AP-07  AP-08    
s-01     -30   -28    -40     -44    -62    -60    -78     -60    -62   
s-01     -30   -52    -38     -44    -62    -60    -78     -60    -68   
s-01     -30   -17    -36     -40    -62    -58    -66     -60    -68   
s-01     -28   -19    -36     -36    -62    -56    -36     -52    -68   
s-01     -28   -17    -36     -40    -54    -56    -36     -52    -64 
...      ...   ...    ...     ...    ...    ...    ...     ...    ...
```

-Shape of data: 15071 rows × 10 columns
-The Target (y) is a square column
-The Features (X) are AP-00  AP-01  AP-02   AP-03  AP-04  AP-05  AP-06   AP-07  AP-08

The Values are Xs are RSSI values, which depends on the collected RSSI values should classify it in the  required square
Square Column is multiclass ( s-01, s-02, s-03)

I fit it with RandomForest Classifier

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.30,random_state = 42)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_hat = clf.predict(x_test)
accuracy_score(y_hat,y_test)
```

0.9838746309334545

-NOTE: Data is balanced, so I thought its overfitting

I decided to make a cross-validation: to X_train and Y_train

```
model = RandomForestClassifier()
scores1 = cross_val_score(model,x_train,y_train, cv = 5)
print(scores1)
array([0.98199513, 0.98199513, 0.98442822, 0.97955209, 0.98344693])
```

Again to X_test and Y_test:

```
scores2 = cross_val_score(model,x_test,y_test, cv = 10)
print(scores2)
array([0.98637911, 0.97048808, 0.97616345, 0.975     , 0.96931818])
```

So, Is that mean my model doesn't overfit? or can explain what is going on? and can it give this accuracy without any hyperparameter tuning !!

Comment: Overfit means although your model performs good at your validation-set, performs poorly in your test-set. I don't see any problem in your `accuracy_score` and `print(scores2)` results. You can say your model is not overfitting.

Comment: @Ahx  aha now I got it, Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not overfiting, so your model is correct.**

As you said, if you obtain similar accuracies values between train and test data, you are not overfitting. Probably your problem is quite easy to solve with these features (lucky hahah).

I recommend you plot which features are the most important for your model, this will help you understand a little bit more which features makes you achieve these huge accuracy:

```
feat_importances = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')
```

Moreover, **Yes, you can obtain such a good accuracy without tuning hyperparameters**. Default hyperparameters usually works pretty well, obviously you can increase the accuracies a little bit changing some fields. Tuning hyperparameters are super useful to avoid overfiting, but it's not your case.